# flet with pypdf2 cannot find file

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf, flet

so I made this app several months ago and it was working fine but now when I ran it now, trying to merge 2 pdf files `1.pdf` and `2.pdf` it, has an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.pdf'` also the when the `Banner_Warning` is shown the dismiss button does not work anymore

I can print the value of the pdf file below so I don't get why it says no such file:

```
for pdf_file in e.files:
            print(f"{pdf_file}")
```

**UPDATE: i can now merge the file using `merger.append(pdf_file.path)` somehow `merger.append(pdf_file.name)` does not work anymore but the file is not saving in the same folder but up one level, so the pdf files are inside `Python Scripts\Flet` but the merged file is being save in `Python Scripts` folder, anybody have an idea how to save in the same folder?**

below is the code and error output:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter

import flet as ft

merger = PdfWriter()


class Banner_Warning(ft.UserControl):
    def __init__(self, text_banner: str) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.text_banner = text_banner

    def close_banner(self, e: ft.ControlEvent) -> None:
        self.banner.open = False
        self.update

    def build(self) -> ft.Banner:
        self.banner = ft.Banner(
            bgcolor=ft.colors.RED_500,
            leading=ft.Icon(
                ft.icons.WARNING_AMBER_ROUNDED, color=ft.colors.AMBER, size=40
            ),
            content=ft.Text(self.text_banner),
            actions=[ft.TextButton("Dismiss", on_click=self.close_banner)],
        )
        self.banner.open = True
        return self.banner


def main(page: ft.page):

    def merge_pdfs(e: ft.FilePickerResultEvent):

        # get file name and password from the corresponding textfields
        merge_file_name = textField_name.value
        file_password = textField_password1.value

        # show warning when no filename is provided
        if not merge_file_name or merge_file_name == " ":
            # banner for when there is error in file name or file selection
            page.add(Banner_Warning("Please check the file name entered."))
            return None

        # show warning if less than 2 files selected
        if not e.files or len(e.files) < 2:
            # banner for when there is error in file name or file selection
            page.add(Banner_Warning("Please select at least 2 files."))
            return None

        # merge all selected pdf files
        for pdf_file in e.files:
            print(f"{pdf_file}")
            merger.append(pdf_file.name)

        # check if user provided password
        if file_password:
            merger.encrypt(file_password, use_128bit=True)

        # save new pdf file using value of entry input
        merger.write(merge_file_name + ".pdf")
        merger.close()

        # show messagebox merger is complete
        page.snack_bar = ft.SnackBar(ft.Text("PDF file merge complete."))
        page.snack_bar.open = True
        page.update()

    pick_files_dialog = ft.FilePicker(on_result=merge_pdfs)
    page.overlay.append(pick_files_dialog)

    page.title = "Merge PDF"
    page.icon = ft.icons.INFO
    page.window_width = 320
    page.window_height = 300
    page.bgcolor = "gray"
    page.window_center()
    page.window_resizable = False
    page.vertical_alignment = "center"
    page.horizontal_alignment = "center"

    textField_name = ft.TextField(
        label="File Name",
        autofocus=True,
        width=250,
        bgcolor="gray",
        color="yellow",
        border_color="yellow",
    )

    textField_password1 = ft.TextField(
        label="Optional Password",
        password=True,
        can_reveal_password=True,
        autofocus=True,
        width=250,
        bgcolor="gray",
        color="yellow",
        border_color="yellow",
    )

    select_merge_button = ft.ElevatedButton(
        "Select and Merge",
        icon=ft.icons.UPLOAD_FILE,
        on_click=lambda _: pick_files_dialog.pick_files(allow_multiple=True),
        color="black",
        bgcolor="white",
        height=50,
        style=ft.ButtonStyle(shape=ft.RoundedRectangleBorder(radius=5)),
    )

    entriesCol = ft.Column(
        spacing=30,
        controls=[textField_name, textField_password1, select_merge_button],
        horizontal_alignment="center",
    )

    page.add(entriesCol)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ft.app(target=main)
```

error output:

```
 File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()




File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 982, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)




 File "C:\Users\GV\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flet_core\event_handler.py", line 28, in __sync_handler
    h(r)




File "c:\Users\GV\Box\Documents\Python Scripts\Flet\flet_merge_pdf_oop.py", line 53, in merge_pdfs       
    merger.append(pdf_file.name)


  File "C:\Users\GV\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PyPDF2\_writer.py", line 2326, in append
    self.merge(

  File "C:\Users\GV\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PyPDF2\_utils.py", line 417, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GV\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PyPDF2\_writer.py", line 2372, in merge
    stream, encryption_obj = self._create_stream(fileobj)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\GV\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PyPDF2\_writer.py", line 2253, in _create_stream
    with FileIO(fileobj, "rb") as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.pdf'
```